# How do I get this url query to work in IE and iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, url, hyperlink

As part of my WordPress post I have a link to a form that the user can fill out to receive recognition for reading the post. I am using gravity forms and url parameters to do this. I pass the page title and id number to hidden fields in gravity forms using URL parameters and then add the page title to the end of the link as an anchor.

On my form page I take the link anchor and parse it to create the title only this does not seem to work in IE 7+ or on iPhone running latest safari and ios 6.

**Example of url at the bottom of a post**

site.com/post/?page-title=Page%20Title&page-ID=1234#Page Title

**After clicking link in IE or iPhone**

site.com/post/?page-title=Page%20Title&page-ID=1234

In iPhone and IE it looks like the Anchor is ommitted, which prevents the title of the page appearing in the form.

Is there a better way to do this? I am using WordPress and do not have the ability to install plugins, edit the theme or access the database or write PHP. I can use Javascript, CSS and HTML.

Thank You

Comment: How are you making this link?

Comment: I use a widget and build the link using shortcodes:
<a href="/?page-title=[the_title]&page-ID=[the_ID]#[the_title]">

Comment: So, what's the issue?  Does the link not work when you click on it?

Comment: When the user click the link in IE or iPhone they end up not seeing the title of the post that they were just reading in the form. Which makes it pretty confusing. I use the anchor to show the page title in the form.

Comment: Going to need more to go on like what version of IE it is and it would be very helpful if you could show us the code (or link to running live).